# GMOD-Custom Gamemode-Teams & VGUI

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I have been coding a new custom gamemode for Gmod, its going to be similar to DarkRP. However, I have hit a wall. When I try to include a lua file I keep getting an error:

This is the error:

```
Couldn't include file '\modules\team\teammenu.lua' (File not found) <@gamemode/spacerp/cl_init.lua> (line 2)
```

Here is the code from my files:

***Init.lua :***

```html
AddCSLuaFile( "shared.lua" )
AddCSLuaFile( "cl_init.lua" )
AddCSLuaFile( "modules/team/teamsetup.lua" )
AddCSLuaFile( "modules/team/teamMenu.lua" )

include( "shared.lua" )
include( "/modules/team/teamsetup.lua" )
include( "modules/team/teamMenu.lua" )

function GM:PlayerInitialSpawn( ply )
 
    ply:ConCommand( "team_menu" )
 
end 

function GM:PlayerSpawn( ply )
 print( "Player: " .. ply:Nick() .. " has spawned!")
 ply:StripWeapons()
 ply:SetupHands()
 
 
end

function GM:PlayerSetHandsModel( ply, ent )

 local simplemodel = player_manager.TranslateToPlayerModelName( ply:GetModel() )
 local info = player_manager.TranslatePlayerHands( simplemodel )
 if ( info ) then
  ent:SetModel( info.model )
  ent:SetSkin( info.skin )
  ent:SetBodyGroups( info.body )
 end

end

function team_red( ply )
 
    ply:SetTeam( 0 )
 
end
 
function team_blue( ply )
 
    ply:SetTeam( 1 )
end
 
concommand.Add( "team_red", team_red )
concommand.Add( "team_blue", team_blue )
```

***cl_init.lua :***

```html
include( "shared.lua" )
include( "/modules/team/teamMenu.lua" )
```

***shared.lua***

```html
GM.Name = "SpaceRP"
GM.Author = "Dicknanigans"
GM.Email = "N/A"
GM.Website = "N/A"

team.SetUp( 0, "Red", Color(255,0,0) )
team.SetUp( 1, "Blue", Color(0,0,255) )
```

***teamMenu.lua***

```html
function set_team()
 
local frame = vgui.Create( "DFrame" )
frame:SetPos( ScrW() / 2, ScrH() / 2 ) --Set the window in the middle of the players screen/game window
frame:SetSize( 200, 210 ) --Set the size
frame:SetTitle( "Change Team" ) --Set title
frame:SetVisible( true )
frame:SetDraggable( false )
frame:ShowCloseButton( true )
frame:MakePopup()
 
team_red = vgui.Create( "DButton", frame )
team_red:SetPos( frame:GetTall() / 2, 5 ) --Place it half way on the tall and 5 units in horizontal
team_red:SetSize( 50, 100 )
team_red:SetText( "Team Red" )
team_red.DoClick = function() --Make the player join team 1
    RunConsoleCommand( "team_red" )
end
 
team_blue = vgui.Create( "DButton", frame )
team_blue:SetPos( frame:GetTall() / 2, 105 ) --Place it next to our previous one
team_blue:SetSize( 50, 100 )
team_blue:SetText( "Team Blue" )
team_blue.DoClick = function() --Make the player join team 2
    RunConsoleCommand( "team_blue" )
end
 
end
concommand.Add( "team_menu", set_team )
```

***teamsetup.lua***

```html
local ply = FindMetaTable( "Player" )

local teams = {}


/*
 THIS IS THE TEAM INIT AREA
*/
teams[0] = {
   name = "red",
   description = "You are on the red team",
   color = Vector(1.0, 0,0),
   weapons = {  "weapon_smg1", "weapon_revolver", "weapon_frag" },
   model = ("models/player/Group01/male_0" .. math.random(1,9) .. ".mdl")
   }
teams[1] = {
   name = "blue",
   description = "You are on the blue team",
   color = Vector(0, 0,1.0),
   weapons = { "weapon_smg1", "weapon_revolver", "weapon_frag" },
   model = ("models/player/Group01/male_0" .. math.random(1,9) .. ".mdl")
   }
   
/* 
 END
*/

function GM:PlayerLoadout( ply ) 
 
 ply:StripWeapons() 
 
 ply:SetupTeam( n )
 
end


function ply:SetupTeam( n )
 if ( not teams[n] ) then return end
 
 self:SetTeam( n )
 self:SetPlayerColor( teams[n].color )
 self:SetHealth( 150 )
 self:SetMaxHealth( 200 )
 self:SetWalkSpeed( 200 )
 self:SetRunSpeed( 400 )
 self:SetModel( teams[n].model )
 
 self:GiveWeapons( n )
end

function ply:GiveWeapons( n )
 for k, weapon in pairs( teams[n].weapons ) do
  self:Give( weapon )
 end
end
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the / at the start of the paths for?

Comment: It's just a habit when I code.

Comment: Can you screenshot your models/team/ folder?